# IOS customkeybord programming extended keys

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I am making a custom IOS keyboard with more than 200 characters and I want to pop a view containing a set of buttons when a key is long pressed.I tried adding a gesture like this when I create the button like this

```
    let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
    longPress.addTarget(self, action: "didLongPress")
    button.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
```

and in the long press action I created a UIView containing a set of buttons and I am confused where to add the subview. does some one know how to add array of keys when long pressed?

Comment: Check this https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/cyrkeyboardbutton

Comment: I was following a tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/custom-keyboard-tutorial/ and searching for an easy way to extend it.